# How can I run a MySQL SELECT query once and use it in a huge insert query?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has around 10,000-20,000 entries entered into it at a time. This table should reference another table by ID, but I don't know what that ID is yet and I need to find it using a MySQL query, with some information that I know about the parent table...

Here's an example of the tables...

```
ParentTable
 - id - int, primary key, auto incriment
 - name - varchar
 - type - varchar

ChildTable
 - id - int, primary key, auto incriment
 - parent_table_id - int
 - name - varchar
```

I need a way to run a MySQL query like this...

```
SELECT id FROM ParentTable WHERE name='SomeName' AND type='SomeType';
```

and then use the result of that MySQL Query to populate ChildTable like so...

```
INSERT INTO ChildTable (parent_table_id, name) VALUES
    (previous_result, "SomeName1"),
    (previous_result, "SomeName2"),
    (previous_result, "SomeName3"),
    (previous_result, "SomeName4000"),
    (previous_result, "SomeName10000"),
    (previous_result, "SomeName20000");
```

The catch is that I only want to run the ParentTable select query ONCE... Is this possible using strictly MySQL?

Comment: Insert rows into temporary table, then do mass insert from joined select.

Comment: I'm kind of rough with MySQL so I'll try and google search how to do that stuff, but do you have suggestions for a tutorial to learn how to do that @Andreas?

Comment: @Ricky, Are you saying all the records have the same parent_table_id?

Comment: @FLICKER yes they do, but I need to find that parent_table_id by running the SELECT query (or a variation of it).

Comment: Can't you run the query, get the parent_id and store it in  a variable and use that variable in your insert statements?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the entire idea is to just pass in both queries as one string into a mysql query and have it auto process.

Comment: So your need to do the select and all inserts using a single query? if so, there must be a way doing that. let me see

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem!

```
SELECT id INTO @parent_id FROM ParentTable WHERE name='SomeName' AND type='SomeType';

INSERT INTO ChildTable (parent_table_id, name)
    VALUES
        (@parent_id, "New"),
        (@parent_id, "New1"),
        (@parent_id, "New2"),
        (@parent_id, "New3"),
        (@parent_id, "New4"),
        (@parent_id, "New5"),
        (@parent_id, "New6");
```

Comment: Using a variable is what I suggested you and you said you cannot do that. BTW, you are storing the id in parent_id but when inserting, you use @warehouse_id. is that a typo?

Comment: Oh I thought you meant to use a variable in a programming language (my queries are run out of C++). I'll boost u for that then, thanks. yes that's a typo, ill fix it.